# Using DateTime for a SQL Time Column in Entity Framework Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Is there a way to make Entity Framework Core let you use a DateTime for a SQL Time column? SQL Server allows you to set a Time column value using a DateTime, but when you try to configure Entity Framework Core to do this, it throws an exception when compiling the model saying that the Database Provider does not support the datatype.

This code throws the exception

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Category> builder)
{
    ...
    builder.Property<System.DateTime>(x => x.StartTime).HasColumnName(@"StartTime").HasColumnType(@"time").IsRequired() 
    // HasColumnType matches the type defined in SQL
}
```

This code works fine, but I'd rather keep HasColumnType accurate so that it doesn't modify the database to use DateTime instead of Time...

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Category> builder)
{
    ...
    builder.Property<System.DateTime>(x => x.StartTime).HasColumnName(@"StartTime").HasColumnType(@"datetime").IsRequired()
    // HasColumnType does not match the type defined in SQL
}
```

Is there a reason EF Core blocks the ability to do this when SQL allows it?

Comment: Use `Timespan` instead. A `time` column contains only the time-of-day, it's not a full `datetime`so it *shouldn't* be mapped to `DateTime`

Comment: I prefer to avoid TimeSpan, it's just a terrible DataType for dealing with the Time of Day, you need a custom binder to map datetime values coming from the client... And SQL Server supports setting a Time field with a DateTime, so why would Entity Framework arbitrarily block that functionality?.

Comment: Because SQL Server *doesn't* support that at all. The legacy `datetime` type has a *lot* of quirks - you could add two `datetime` values and get a date in 4040 for example. That doesn't mean it's a good idea. That's why SQL Server *doesn't* allow implicit conversions between `time` and the newer types like `datetime2`

Comment: As for terrible types, it's `DateTime` that's terrible. Time-of-Day doesn't have a date component at all, so what is a `DateTime` supposed to mean? How could you compare times when all you have are `DateTime` values? While `Timespan` may not be restricted to just 24 hours, it's a *lot* better than `DateTime` though. There's no need for a custom binder either - `time` maps to `Timespan`, not `DateTime`

Comment: In the end, `time` map to `Timespan` in  EF.

Comment: You need a custom binder to bind the posted values since JavaScript has no concept of a TimeSpan or Time... It would be nice if the Server and Client data types could be compatible. Also, to properly format a TimeSpan for 12 hour display, you need to add it to a DateTime then format the DateTime; it just feels like .Net is hacking the TimeSpan in to work with Time when they should just introduce a Time DataType. TimeSpan should be a TimeSpan, not a Time of Day.

Comment: Javascript has nothing to do with the ORM that runs *behind* an API. Frankly, Javascript doesn't even have a decent Datetime type, which is why moment.js exists. That's a Javascript problem though, not Timespan's fault. Again (and again) the default mapping is Timestamp. If you don't want it, you'll have to write custom code.

Comment: And time of day or Timespan has no format, just like `DateTime` has no format. Both are binary values. You're trying to use EF Core to solve a Javascript problem. It's *that* attempt that should be considered a hack. In Javascript, you have to use `moment.js` to format any kind of date or time too

Comment: `when they should just introduce a Time DataType` there are two experimental `Date` and `Time` types. This won't make Javascript work any better though. Time is *far* more complex that just time-of-day though. What about timezones and DST rules? What's the timezone for a `time` value, how do you display it when the client uses a different timezone? Applications that really care about time end up using libraries like NodaTime instead of the built-in types.

Comment: None of this changes the fact that SQL supports populating a Time field with DateTime and DateTime2 values, but Entity Framework Core arbitrarily blocks the functionality.


INSERT INTO MyTable(Name, Time) VALUES ('Time', SYSDATETIME())


-- Time is time(7), SYSDATETIME() returns DateTime2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up resolving this with a Conversion

```
builder.Property<DateTime>("StartTime").HasColumnName(@"StartTime").HasColumnType(@"time").IsRequired().HasConversion(v => v.TimeOfDay, v => DateTime.Now.Date.Add(v));
```